# ICheck plugin not working with sublist in Knockout.js

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, icheck

I have a Knockout model containing a bool observable and a list of objects that contain a bool observable.

I have custom binding `iCheckedSys`, for the bool in the model, to work with iCheck, and custom binding `iCheckedPrimary` to work with iCheck on the bool in the objects in the model's list.

`iCheckedSys` functions correctly, and `valueAccessor()` returns observable.
However in the list, `valueAccessor()` returns false in `iCheckedPrimary`.

If I just use checkbox for the list objects, it works just fine.

How can I have iCheck work with the list objects?
Thanks much.

```html
<div class="form-horizontal no-margin form-border" data-bind="UserViewModel">
   <label>
      <input type="checkbox" data-bind="iChecked: IsSysAdmin">
   </label>

   <tbody data-bind="foreach: RolesList">
      <td><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: IsPrimary" /></td>
   </tbody>
</div>
```

```
<script>
var Role = function () {
   var self = this;
   self.ID = ko.observable();
   self.IsPrimary = ko.observable();
};

var UserViewModel = function () {
   var self = this;
   self.ID = ko.observable(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.ID)));
   self.IsSysAdmin = ko.observable(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.IsSysAdmin)));
   self.RolesList = ko.observableArray();

   ko.bindingHandlers.iChecked = {
      init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
         $(element).iCheck({
            checkboxClass: "icheckbox_minimal-green",
            radioClass: "iradio_minimal-green", increaseArea: "20%"
         });
         $(element).on('ifChanged', function () {
            var observable = valueAccessor();
            observable($(element)[0].checked);
         });
      },
      update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
         var value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
         if (value) {
            $(element).iCheck('check');
         } else {
            $(element).iCheck('uncheck');
         }
      }
   };
};

var viewModel = new UserViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized that regardless of with record I changed iCheckedPri in, only the last record in viewModel.RolesList was being passed in valueAccessor. So the current record and it's value wasn't being accessed.

I don't know if this is the proper way...
but instead of the value, I passed iCheck with the record object itself and updated it with the current checkbox value, and updated iCheck (check/uncheck) with the object value.

```html
<td><input type="checkbox" data-bind="iCheckedPri: $rawData"></td>
```

```
ko.bindingHandlers.iCheckedPri = {

        $(element).on('ifChanged', function (event) {
            var observable = valueAccessor();
            observable = $(element)[0].checked;
            valueAccessor().IsPrimary = this.checked;
        });
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
        if (value.IsPrimary) {
            $(element).iCheck('check');
        } else {
            $(element).iCheck('uncheck');
        }
    }
};
```